# R Shiny: How to add pagination in DT::renderDataTable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to add pagination, search box and selector in my R Shiny app, but it doesn't work for now (I tried paging = TRUE and                                 searching = TRUE, in options as you can see bellow but it doesn't work). Do you have any idea of what I should add?

```
output$mytable1  <- DT::renderDataTable(
                            DT::datatable(
                                { plots.dfs()[[1]] },
                                caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
                                    style = 'caption-side: bottom; text-align: center;',
                                    'Table 2: ', htmltools::em('This is a simple caption for the table.')
                                ),
                                extensions = 'Buttons',

                                options = list(
                                    paging = TRUE,
                                    searching = TRUE,
                                    fixedColumns = TRUE,
                                    autoWidth = TRUE,
                                    ordering = TRUE,
                                    dom = 'tB',
                                    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel')
                                ),

                                class = "display"
                           ))
```

I have added a screenshot of table I have now, and the expected table.
Thanks for your help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s05Sh.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) parameter, for example as follows:

```
DT::datatable(
  { mtcars },
  caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
    style = 'caption-side: bottom; text-align: center;',
    'Table 2: ', htmltools::em('This is a simple caption for the table.')
  ),
  extensions = 'Buttons',

  options = list(
    fixedColumns = TRUE,
    autoWidth = TRUE,
    ordering = TRUE,
    dom = 'Bftsp',
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel')
  ))
```

---

[image]

---

To add page length, also add `l` to the string. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, by adding dom='Bftsp', features now appear!