# data table disappear after editing in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make an editable and downloadable data table in shiny app. After I edit the table, the data table automatically disappear for some reason. This only happen when the data `dat` is reactive (which is necessary in my app).

Does anyone knows what is going on? Thanks a lot.

example code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("nrow",
                "num of rows",
                choices = 1:5,
                selected = 3,
                multiple = FALSE),
    DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){

    dat = reactive({
        iris[1:as.integer(input$nrow),]
    })

    output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
        datatable(dat(), editable = "cell", extensions = "Buttons", 
                  options = list(
                      dom = "Bfrtip",
                      buttons = list(
                          "csv"
                      )
                  ))
    })

    observeEvent(input[["table_cell_edit"]], {
        cellinfo <- input[["table_cell_edit"]]
        dat() <<- editData(dat(), input[["table_cell_edit"]], "table")
    })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You can try replacing `dat()` with `dat` in your `observeEvent`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("nrow","num of rows",choices = 1:5,selected = 3,multiple = FALSE),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  v <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$nrow,{
    v$dat <- iris[1:as.integer(input$nrow),]
  })

  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(v$dat, editable = "cell", extensions = "Buttons", options = list(dom = "Bfrtip",buttons = list("excel")))
  })

  observeEvent(input[["table_cell_edit"]], {
    cellinfo <- input[["table_cell_edit"]]
    v$dat <<- editData(v$dat, input[["table_cell_edit"]], "table")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it OK like this ? A possible unwanted behavior is that the table is reset after changing the number of rows. But I don't think we can avoid that... since these are two different tables.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("nrow",
              "num of rows",
              choices = 1:5,
              selected = 3,
              multiple = FALSE),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  dat0 <- iris
  dat <- reactiveVal()
  observe({
    dat(dat0[1:as.integer(input$nrow),])
  })

  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat(), editable = "cell", extensions = "Buttons", 
              options = list(
                dom = "Bfrtip",
                buttons = list(
                  "csv"
                )
              ))
  })

  observeEvent(input[["table_cell_edit"]], {
    cellinfo <- input[["table_cell_edit"]]
    dat(editData(dat(), input[["table_cell_edit"]], "table"))
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```